# Get ID of Button for Switch Statement: MFC

Tags: visual-c++, button, mfc, filechooser

**Language:** Visual C++, MFC

**Environment:** Visual Studio 2005

I have a dialog that requires the user to set file paths for six different settings. Each text box has a browse button which launches a file browser.

How can I set it up so that all of the browse buttons all call the same function to launch the chooser, then use a switch to determine which button invoked the file chooser so that I can set the text of the appropriate CEdit box with the path? // *run-on sentence, hah*

I'm sure I'll have to use **GetDlgCtrlID**, I'm just not sure how.

Thank you for your help in advance!

~ Jon

EDIT: Here's the code I have now...very simple because I'm just getting it to work for now.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(FSC_3DPersp, CSAPrefsSubDlg)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(FSC_3DPersp)
    // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add message map macros here
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
ON_COMMAND(BN_CLICKED, &FSC_3DPersp::Browse)
 END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

// FSC_3DPersp message handlers

```
void FSC_3DPersp::Browse(UINT uiID)
{
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

switch(uiID)
{
case IDC_BUTTON1: 
    MessageBox("1");
    break;
case IDC_BUTTON2:
    MessageBox("2");
    break;
case IDC_BUTTON3:
    MessageBox("3");
    break;
case IDC_BUTTON4:
    MessageBox("4");
    break;
case IDC_BUTTON5:
    MessageBox("5");
    break;
case IDC_BUTTON6:
    MessageBox("6");
    break;
case IDC_BUTTON7:
    MessageBox("7");
    break;
}
}

BOOL FSC_3DPersp::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
{
    Browse(LOWORD(wParam));
    return TRUE;
}
return CWnd::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're responding to the [`BN_CLICKED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761825(v=vs.85).aspx) message, the button ID will be contained in the [`LOWORD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632659(v=vs.85).aspx) of the `wparam` of the message.

**Edit:** MFC normally discards the `wparam` of the message. To access it you must override the [`OnCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t3ddsb9(v=vs.90).aspx) handler in your dialog.

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)
    {
        Browse(LOWORD(wParam));
        return TRUE;
    }
    return CWnd::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that works. This is what I'm using:

ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &FSC_3DPersp::Browse)

So each button 1-7 calls Browse() and it's within this function that I wish to have a switch.

Comment: EDIT: I've added the code I have, but I'm not sure I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: @Mark, thought I had it before, still having a bit of trouble. See my edit above. I don't think I fully understand macros and the OnCommand function.

Comment: Also, I'm still getting the following error ---- 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall FSC_3DPersp::* )(UINT)' to 'AFX_PMSG'

Comment: @Jon, get rid of the ON_COMMAND in your message map and add the prototype for the OnCommand method in your .h file: `virtual BOOL OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);`

Comment: Got it! Everything works now. Thanks again for all the help, Mark! I seriously appreciate it. Have a great day.

Comment: @Jon, one more thing to watch out for - if you have any buttons other than the ones you want to go to the Browse function, you need to check for more than just BN_CLICKED in the OnCommand method. See the answer from [Marius Bancila](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335095/get-id-of-button-for-switch-statement-mfc/6335913#6335913) to get around the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`ON_COMMAND` expects a function that has no arguments. For your `Browse` method you should use `ON_CONTROL_RANGE` macro:

```
ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED, IDC_BUTTON1, IDC_BUTTON7, Browse)
```

You should make sure `IDC_BUTTON1` to `IDC_BUTTON7` have consecutive numerical values.

You can read this article for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84xtde24.aspx.

Comment: This is an even better answer than mine, if you have the discipline to number the button IDs consecutively.

Comment: I had originally experimented with the control range, but wasn't sure how to implement it. I'll try this out because my buttons are consecutively numbered.